# Gluon Scene Builder 16.0.0 does not launch in Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

When trying to launch the latest Gluon Scene Builder release, 16.0.0, nothing happens.  The process shows up in Task Manager but the window does not actually display on the screen.  I have confirmed that I am able to install release 8.5.0 and it launches just fine.  I have also tried running the 16.0.0 installer as Administrator but that also did not launch after installation.  Am I missing a configuration step that was not there for previous versions of Scene Builder?

The scenebuilder.cfg files for the two versions look like this:

```
[Application] 
app.classpath=$APPDIR\scenebuilder-16.0.0-all.jar 
app.mainclass=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp 

[JavaOptions] 
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=16.0.0 
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED –
```

---

```
[Application] 
app.name=SceneBuilder 
app.mainjar=dist.jar 
app.version=8.5.0 
app.preferences.id=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app 
app.mainclass=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/SceneBuilderApp 
app.classpath= 
app.runtime=$APPDIR\runtime 
app.identifier=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app 

[JVMOptions] 
[JVMUserOptions] 
[ArgOptions] –
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Scene Builder 16.0.0 runs just fine on my Windows 10, 64 bit machine. If I remember correctly, all I did was download the installer and run it. Do you see a log file at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\scenebuilder-16.0.0.log`? If so, are there any errors being reported?

Comment: Make sure you remove 8.5.0 before installing 16.0.0. This seems to be related to this [reported issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues/368).

Comment: I have searched and cannot find that log file, scenebuilder-16.0.0.log, anywhere on my desktop.  Also 8.5.0 was already uninstalled before I reinstalled 16.0.0.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  I uninstalled 8.5.0 before the 16.0.0 install.  I also have confirmed that the reported issue is not my problem because i can successfully run the JVM from command line.  Please find below the screenbuilder.cfg file for both versions.  I am wondering if the 16.0.0 is missing lines.

Comment: Version 8.5.0

[Application]
app.name=SceneBuilder
app.mainjar=dist.jar
app.version=8.5.0
app.preferences.id=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app
app.mainclass=com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/SceneBuilderApp
app.classpath=
app.runtime=$APPDIR\runtime
app.identifier=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app

[JVMOptions]

[JVMUserOptions]

[ArgOptions]

Comment: Version 16.0.0

[Application]
app.classpath=$APPDIR\scenebuilder-16.0.0-all.jar
app.mainclass=com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp

[JavaOptions]
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=16.0.0
java-options=--add-opens=javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: @ItachiUchiha  I also confirmed that my issue is not the reported issue because I can successfully run the JVM from command line

Comment: You can add scenebuilder.cfg to the original question. Also, how do you execute JVM from command line?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha   The problem in the reported issue that you linked had to do with the JVM .  The first check they stated was to run a check of the java version from the command line, which for that issue yields an error   <...\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder>runtime\bin\java -version
<JAVA_HOME>/lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use -classpath instead.
.Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: I can successfully check the java version  using the java executable that is in \runtime\bin